# Chrome Extension | Replace Website JavaScript File via Wildcard

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am able to replace the JavaScript file, which is served by a webpage and Chrome will use my changed script. Here is the solution:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "extension name",
  "description": "extension descriptin",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {"scripts":["background.js"]},
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "*://examplesite.com/*",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        if (details.url == "http://examplesite.com/script.8g5d8wssgf45s.combined.js")
            return {
                redirectUrl: "http://myexamplesite.com/my_modified_script.js"
            };
    }, {
        urls: ["*://examplesite.com/script*.js"]
    },
    ["blocking"]);
```

This works well - the browser will ignore script `script.8g5d8wssgf45s.combined.js` and instead of this will use my modified version from `http://myexamplesite.com/my_modified_script.js`.
I can't figure out, how to do some wildcard match of the script. Because its name is changing frequently - now it is `script.8g5d8wssgf45s.combined.js` but when developers release a new version, a script name will have another hash in name, for example: `script.azz561sscbdf.combined.js`
Is possible to do some wildcard match in condition, like this?:

```
if (details.url == "http://examplesite.com/script.*.combined.js")
```

That there will be some wildcard mark `*` and it will accept all future version changes, of the script and replaces it?

And another question - can I serve my modified version of the script locally? That it will be packed in my extension. Or the only way is to serve it via my page, like in this case: `http://myexamplesite.com/my_modified_script.js`?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution with regex, it searches for "**script.**" filename:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        if (details.url.match(/^.*\b(script.)\b.*$/))
            return {
                redirectUrl: "http://myexamplesite.com/my_modified_script.js"
            };
    }, {
        urls: ["*://examplesite.com/*"]
    },
    ["blocking"]);
```

Inspired from: https://github.com/bendavis78/chrome-extension-redirector/blob/master/redirector/background.js